# Failed PV in VG unable to break mirrors

Tags: fedora, lvm, disk, raid1

I have a linux (fedora 30) machine with a single VG and multiple mirrored LVs.
I had the LVs mirrored on two PVs but one PV failed and I wanted to move from 2TB PVs to 4TB PVs anyway so I added a new PV and chanced all of my LVs to three mirrors (m=2).
So now I have my LVs all safely mirrored and it is time to remove the bad drive. 
But "lvconvert -m1 LVNAME PV2REMOVE" says that won't work perhaps you should consider "vgreduce --removemissing"

Which of course does nothing
and from what I've read using the "--force" option will throw away all of my LVs

**lvs -a -o +devices | tr -s '\t ' '  '**

```
 LV VG Attr LSize Pool Origin Data% Meta% Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert Devices 
 NAS VG2TB rwi-aor-r- 200.00g 100.00 NAS_rimage_0(0),NAS_rimage_1(0) 
 [NAS_rimage_0] VG2TB vwi-aor-r- 200.00g 
 [NAS_rimage_1] VG2TB iwi-aor--- 200.00g /dev/sdb1(392715) 
 [NAS_rmeta_0] VG2TB ewi-aor-r- 4.00m 
 [NAS_rmeta_1] VG2TB ewi-aor--- 4.00m /dev/sdb1(392714) 
 PythonNAS VG2TB rwi-aor-r- 100.00g 100.00 PythonNAS_rimage_0(0),PythonNAS_rimage_1(0),PythonNAS_rimage_2(0) 
 [PythonNAS_rimage_0] VG2TB vwi-aor-r- 100.00g 
 [PythonNAS_rimage_1] VG2TB vwi-aor-r- 100.00g 
 [PythonNAS_rimage_2] VG2TB iwi-aor--- 100.00g /dev/sdb1(341512) 
 [PythonNAS_rmeta_0] VG2TB ewi-aor-r- 4.00m 
 [PythonNAS_rmeta_1] VG2TB ewi-aor-r- 4.00m 
 [PythonNAS_rmeta_2] VG2TB ewi-aor--- 4.00m /dev/sdb1(341511) 
 lv_VM_Data VG2TB rwi-a-r-r- 200.00g 100.00 lv_VM_Data_rimage_0(0),lv_VM_Data_rimage_1(0),lv_VM_Data_rimage_2(0) 
 [lv_VM_Data_rimage_0] VG2TB vwi-aor-r- 200.00g 
 [lv_VM_Data_rimage_1] VG2TB vwi-aor-r- 200.00g 
 [lv_VM_Data_rimage_2] VG2TB iwi-aor--- 200.00g /dev/sdb1(290311) 
 [lv_VM_Data_rmeta_0] VG2TB ewi-aor-r- 4.00m 
 [lv_VM_Data_rmeta_1] VG2TB ewi-aor-r- 4.00m 
 [lv_VM_Data_rmeta_2] VG2TB ewi-aor--- 4.00m /dev/sdb1(290310) 
 lv_VM_Root VG2TB rwi-aor-r- 60.00g 100.00 lv_VM_Root_rimage_0(0),lv_VM_Root_rimage_1(0),lv_VM_Root_rimage_2(0) 
 [lv_VM_Root_rimage_0] VG2TB vwi-aor-r- 60.00g 
 [lv_VM_Root_rimage_1] VG2TB vwi-aor-r- 60.00g 
 [lv_VM_Root_rimage_2] VG2TB iwi-aor--- 60.00g /dev/sdb1(367113) 
 [lv_VM_Root_rmeta_0] VG2TB ewi-aor-r- 4.00m 
 [lv_VM_Root_rmeta_1] VG2TB ewi-aor-r- 4.00m 
 [lv_VM_Root_rmeta_2] VG2TB ewi-aor--- 4.00m /dev/sdb1(367112)
```

Comment: Perhaps the bad drive has already been auto-removed from the mirror you're trying to convert? What is the output of `lvs -a -o +devices`?

Comment: @telcoM   --  I added a partial output from that to my OP. The complete output was just way too long even after I changed all the spaces into single tabs.  Also please not that I have removed the other PV from the VG. I thought that if I leave one PV untouched I can be a bit more "adventurous" with the "fix" and still have a backup of my data.  Perhaps what I need to do is export in and then import what is on the disk?

Answer (score 1):

Exactly how did you remove the other PV?

It looks like as far as LVM knows, the only up-to-date copy of your data is on `/dev/sdb1` - all the other copies are virtual and in need of syncing. As a result, you might have to first `lvchange --refresh <LV>` to get all the accessible PVs into sync.

If the other PVs are no longer visible to the system (i.e. either totally dead or you have pulled them out), add a new PV to the VG and then run `lvconvert --repair <name of LV> [new PV]`. If LVM still sees the bad disk, the command is `lvconvert --replace <old PV> <name of LV> [new PV]`.

If you are familiar with other Unix variants' LVM, note that Linux's LVM export/import logic works very differently. In Linux, the equivalent of other Unixes' "import" normally happens automatically when either new devices are detected or you run `vgscan` manually - and `vgscan` is pretty safe: if it detects any sort of conflicts, it won't override any part of active LVM configuration with conflicting one, it just tells you what's wrong and expects you to fix it before trying `vgscan` again.

The "export" operation in Linux LVM is actually more like "prevent automatic and manual activation of this VG: if an exported VG is found out to be conflicting with any other VG, ignore the exported VG". The "import" operation just removes this attribute. So it's useful when preparing to move a set of disks encompassing a LVM VG to another host, but otherwise it may be less useful than you think.

Comment: telcoM  -- Thanks for your answers.  
I was mistaken when I said that the "vgreduce --removemissing --force" would remove my LVs.
Maybe it got changed in a newer version.
Last night I had tried "lvconvert -m0 $LV" it complained that I hadn't told it what PV to not use.

Comment: -- Thank you again.
When I reviewed the situation today, after reading your comment,  (I removed the drives by detaching the SATA cable from the drive)
I saw that the PVs were gone but the mirrors remained.
I tried  "lvconvert -m1 $LV" and it worked!!!!
So once I had all of the LVs at m=1 I went to "lvconvert -m0 $LV" and that worked too.
So now after adding in a new PV and remirroring all my LVs I am happily waiting for them to finish syncing before I call it complete